# Hibernate criteria query in multiple levels of entity inheritance

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss

If you have multiple levels of inheritance in a single_table fashion, for instance class

```
class LivingCreatures {}, 

class Animals extends LivingCreatures {}, 

class Dog extends Animals {}, 

class Cat extends Animals {}
```

I've noticed that there is only one discriminator column in the database layer.

Is there a way to ask LivingCreatures for all animals?

```
session().createCriteria(LivingCreatures.class).add(   
     Restrictions.eq("class", Animals.class)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
session.createCriteria(LivingCreatures.class, "creatures").add(Restrictions.eq("creatures.class", Animals.class));
```

This would return only those `LivingCreatures` whose `dtype` is `Animals`, and wouldn't return `Dog`s or `Cat`s. If you want all `Animals` including sub types, `createCriteria(Animals.class`) should work.

Comment: The thing is that with createCriteria(Animals.class) is that there is no information in the database table ( LivingCreatures ) that says that an entry is an Animal. But perhaps the criteria api handles that. I will try later.

Comment: Given the above is Animals then a @MappedSuperclass?

Comment: @SecretService As @AlanHay said, is `Animals` a `@MappedSuperclass` or a base entity which others extend? If it is an entity, it will have its discrimination value stored in `dtype` column.